# episode and # -- can the two be used together?

Tags: grammar, word-request, reading-aloud

For example, on the Internet, there's a podcast for ESL learners called [Culips](http://esl.culips.com/) (they are based in Montreal, Canada). They have two kinds of podcasts there—one is called *Catchword* and the other one *Chatterbox*. When they begin their podcasts, they usually say something like this, *"Hello, English learners and we're back with another Chatterbox episode for you."* I've recently started downloading their podcasts and now I want to give the files that I've downloaded proper titles (in so-called MP3 tags). I was just wondering what would be the right way (grammatically, semantically or whatever) to name a particular episode of the podcast. For instance:

> Catchword Episode 156: Movers and Shakers

Does that sound alright to you? Or maybe this one is better (with the pound sign):

> Catchword Episode #156: Movers and Shakers

And how would you say that now? *"catchword episode number one hundred fifty-six"*?

Please feel free to chime in with your suggestions.

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking 1 how to title the episodes as mp3 files, 2 how to refer to episodes already given an mp3 title, or 3 how to refer to the episodes in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way is fine.  The concept of a podcast "episode number" is similar to the concept of a magazine "issue number".  Similarly, the concept of a podcast "season number" is similar to the concept of a magazine "volume number".

**Abbreviation or Omission of "Number"**:

Including "Number" (abbreviated to "#") is more formal.  The "#" abbreviation is about as informal as omitting "Number".  It is OK to omit the "Number" (or "#"), because the episode number (such as "156") is obviously a number. Some computerized databases have trouble storing (or displaying) the "#" sign.

Other abbreviations for "Number" are "num." and "no."  I recommend avoiding the "no." abbreviation, because it is easy to confuse it with the English word "no".

**Pronunciation:**

"Catchword Episode 156" could be pronounced as either "Catchword Episode one fifty-six" or "Catchword Episode number one fifty-six".

"Catchword Episode #156" would be pronounced as "Catchword Episode number one fifty-six".

If the reader is being very formal, the reader would say "one hundred fifty-six" instead of "one fifty-six".